# Android - InterstitialAd - The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

I am trying to add an InterstitialAd to my project. I have added the necessary library

1. Downloading google service from sdk manager
2. Importing the project as android code
3. Adding it inside the properties>library

Here is my code:

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    ...
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("a152caa4c3be05b");

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        ...

        displayInterstitial();
    }

    ...

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }

 }
```

and here is the logcat

```
 01-08 08:30:00.615: D/dalvikvm(669): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1769811527.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
 01-08 08:30:00.705: D/dalvikvm(669): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-1769811527.jar' (success) ---
 01-08 08:30:00.705: D/dalvikvm(669): DEX prep '/data/data/info.androidhive.tabsswipe/cache/ads-1769811527.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 88ms
 01-08 08:30:00.745: I/Ads(669): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("5CEAF7E172F8B76E72193FA048D8DCB1") to get test ads on this device.
 01-08 08:30:00.755: I/Ads(669): Starting ad request.
 01-08 08:30:00.945: W/ResourceType(669): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 1
 01-08 08:30:00.945: W/ResourceType(669): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
 01-08 08:30:00.945: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(669): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
 01-08 08:30:01.275: W/ResourceType(669): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 1
 01-08 08:30:01.275: W/ResourceType(669): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
 01-08 08:30:01.275: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(669): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
 01-08 08:30:01.280: W/ResourceType(669): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 1
 01-08 08:30:01.280: W/ResourceType(669): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
 01-08 08:30:01.280: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(669): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
 01-08 08:30:01.505: W/InputMethodManager(669): Ignoring onBind: cur seq=1831, given seq=1830
 01-08 08:30:01.505: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(669): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
 01-08 08:30:01.565: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(669): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
 01-08 08:30:01.565: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(669): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 01-08 08:30:01.620: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(669): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 01-08 08:30:02.625: I/Ads(669): Ad finished loading.
```

It looks like the ads is loading well, but nothing is displayed on the screen.
I am not using any other google api (as I have read all the subject about this and people are always having problem when using both adMob and any other google api)

Do you have an idea about how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem, maybe I missed some configuration step...

Comment: You should call displayInterstitial() later. Now, you call it in onCreate and it may not be loaded completed. Try call it in a button onclick handler or something.

Answer (score 1):

Go to admob page and create new interstitial(MY_AD_UNIT_ID). Do not use old Banner id.

Maybe this help you: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3052638?hl=en

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);         
  // Create the interstitial.
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

            // Create ad request.
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onAdLoaded() {
                     displayInterstitial();
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onAdClosed() {
                 }
             });
            // Begin loading your interstitial.
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
      }
     // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
      public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }
```

Comment: This is what fixed my problem, I was using a banned ad id for my interstitial ad.. Thank you so much, was stuck on this one for ages.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search seems to confirm that this

```
01-08 08:30:00.945: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(669): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

is a common log emssage with GPS. But it doesn't seem to have impact. Ie it is benign.

Comment: William is right. Same answer from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#resourcesnotfound

Answer (score 0):

I maybe answer a bit late, but I guess the reason might just be that your ad does not have time to load before being showed.

In your code, you want to display the ad right after you loaded it, it does not leave enough time.

You should place the call `displayInterstitial();` later in your code.